# How can I connect to Linux from Automatic UC4?

Tags: uc4

I have a scenario to develop in UC4, that is encrypt the files and zip it. 
In UC4 I have taken the objects as below :

```
            Login Object
            Unix Jobs object
```

Configured the login object with Linux credentials, 
and 
Unix jobs object : UNIX tab > command : ls -ltr

```
               process tab > ls
                             echo test
                             ping -c 127.0.0.1
                             sleep 5
```

But when I execute this Job, I can't see any output in Last Report. 
I am new to UC4, can anyone please guide me on configure the UC4 for Linux and see the output.

Comment: Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Got the solution, you can regret my query.. Thanks.